# Trying to add elements to a Vector classified with a Struct

Tags: c++

I'm making a program to basically show the statistics about words the user enters. The rest of the program is fine so far, but I'm having a hard time adding words to a `vector` of type `WordCount`.

I have looked around and found several answers, which I would've thought could solve my issue, but I either get a very weird compiler error or it just does not work. I have tried using `emplace_back` and `push_back` with calls I thought was right. In essence, my problem code is as follows:

```cs
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std; //for simplicity here

struct WordCount {
    string word;
    int count;
    //I have tried using this too:
    WordCount(string _word, int _count) : word{_word}, count{_count} {}
};

//...//

void wordToVector(/**...**/,string addStr, vector<WordCount>& wordStats){

/**... code that I've tested to work; basically determined if the 
word was already said as I need to have unique words only...**/

    wordStats.push_back(WordCount(addStr, 1));

/** also tried: (some had "#include <istream>" when using emplace_back
but that didn't seem to make a difference for me in any case)

wordStats.emplace_back(WordCount(addStr, 1));
wordStats.emplace_back({addStr, 1});
wordStats.push_back(addStr, 1)
wordStats.push_back(addStr).word; (and wordStats.push_back(1).count;)
**/
}

int main() {
    vector<WordCount> wordStats(1); //"1" to initialize the size
    wordStats.at(0).word = "";
    wordStats.at(0).count = 0;

    /**There's already a part to change the first values to what they should
be, and it worked last I tested it. Below is a part was for my
personal use to see if anything came out... if it worked**/

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << wordStats.at(i).word << endl;
        cout << wordStats.at(i).count << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I must use a vector for this and cannot use pointers (as I've seen suggested) or `#include <algorithm>` per the instructions. If I typed in "Oh happy day!", it should be able to print (when fixed, with the current cout statements):

OH

1

HAPPY

1

DAY

1

(There's an earlier part that capitalizes every letter, which I tested to work).
This is my first post here because I'm lost. Please let me know if I provided too much or not enough. **Edited formatting

Comment: The code as you provide it doesn't make it possible for anyone to fully reproduce your problem, so I would suggest adding the missing code pieces. Also, what isn't clear to me and is what output you are actually getting or which errors.

Comment: @Lukas Schulte The thing is we're also required to have separate ```.cpp``` and ```.h``` files for the functions, along with having a separate header file for the Struct we make. I tried to compact it as best as possible. If you'd like to see the compiler errors, here's a doc with them:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RxKHHilqj58FveeixlAqbQ8rsnPUPRDRU0C9SmOMX3Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct WordCount {
    string word;
    int count;
};

void wordToVector(string addStr, vector<WordCount>& wordStats){
    for (int i = 0; i < wordStats.size(); i++) {
        if (wordStats[i].word == addStr) {
            wordStats[i].count = wordStats[i].count + 1;
            return;
        }
    }
    struct WordCount wc;
    wc.word = addStr;
    wc.count = 1;
    wordStats.push_back(wc);
}

int main() {
    vector<WordCount> wordStats;
    wordToVector("hehe", wordStats);
    wordToVector("hehe", wordStats);
    wordToVector("haha", wordStats);


    for (int i = 0; i < wordStats.size(); i++) {
        cout << wordStats.at(i).word << endl;
        cout << wordStats.at(i).count << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using this code I get output:

```
hehe
2
haha
1
```

Is there anything else that needs to be added?

If you want to split the input by the spaces and check for occurrences of every word in the input it could be quite inefficient for longer texts to check for every word (Would be linear I think with M*N complexity), so if you are allowed I do suggest to use a map with word as key and value as the amount of occurrences - or something in that fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback and that looks way better than anything I tried. However, my compiler says "No matching constructor for initialization of 'struct WordCount' " for the "wc" part of ```struct WordCount wc;```. Any idea what this means or how to resolve it? And, unfortunately, we aren't allowed to use maps in the course yet.

Comment: What compiler are you using?
with $ g++ -v I get gcc Version 7.4.0 (GCC).
And did you remove the constructor from the struct? I am using the default way to initialize structs here.
See: https://blog.petrzemek.net/2015/10/03/structures-and-member-initializers-in-cpp/

Comment: I was using CLion and it turns out I un-commented the construct in the struct. It compiled afterward. Thank you so much! I would upvote if I could...